Why do my mobile phone photos appear corrupted when downloading as DNG into Photoscape X Pro?
When downloading mobile phone photos as DNG files into Photoscape X Pro, they appear corrupted. What can I do to fix this?

PhotoScape X does not appear to be a Microsoft application. Are you sure it supports DNG files? How are you getting the files from the phone into the application? What operating system is PhotoScape X running on? Try to do the file transfer as a standalone operation first, and then import/open the files in your application of choice after you have used a reliable data transfer method.

Maybe this question will be better here: https://superuser.com/

@RomeoNinov There are 3 search results for photoscape at [su], and 7 results here. I think this is probably the best place for OP's question in the SE sites.

Does Photoscape X support DNG files? I tried searching, but nothing definitive either way. Here's a month-old (as of July 2024) DPReview forum post seems to indicate it doesn't.

Try free 32-bit IrfanView, and add the Cam-Raw plugin for DNG, https://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm,. Why 32-bit? Many plugins do not work on the 64-bit version -- but the 32-bit version runs well on 64-bit machines, whether Windows, or under wine in Linux.
